# How do you say "He is really good at playing soccer"?

Tags: adjetivos, preguntas, deportes

How do you say "He is really good at playing soccer"?
Is it:

> El es jugar el fútbol muy bien.

Comment: Can you break your question down into the specific parts about which you have doubts? This will make it easier for us to address your specific concerns, since we aren't a translation service.

Answer (score 3):

Es realmente bueno jugando al fútbol.

Answer (score 2):

Who would use a high-brow adverb like 'realmente' in such a casual context? "Realmente" is a big word in Spain, and it is plausible that the suggestions given above are influenced by the overuse of the word "really" in English-speaking cultures.

Try, "Es muy bueno jugando a fútbol" or "es muy buen jugador de fútbol."

Even more natural: "Juega de maravilla." Or, "Da gusto verle jugar."

Answer (score 0):

Although the exact translatation for that is:

> Él es realmente bueno jugando al soccer.

I would like to say that, we don't use soccer that much, we prefer to use **Fútbol** (football) because in latin America and Spain we play more soccer than the sport you know for football in USA. Another way to say the same could be

```
Él es un jugador de fútbol realmente bueno.
```

(He is a really good soccer player.)

Answer (score 0):

"Se le da bien/mal X" is a construction in Spanish that means "(s)he's good at X". (Note: Don't try to translate it literally.)

So, in this case,

> Se le da muy bien el fútbol.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the *dársele bien* structure that user3206227 gives, if the thing one is good at a verb, the structure "X is really good at Y<sub>ing</sub>" can also be rendered quite naturally into Spanish as "X Y<sub>X</sub> muy bien" or similar.

So in your example, you would have:

> Él juega al fútbol muy bien